# Unhide description with popup in my table (html text-overflow ellipsis)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, here is my sample code:

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/L604s0rz/)

1. I would like to popup my hidden long description text correctly.
   I can unhide it, but why is the short description cell of my table is so un-fit?(like as border and width of my cell)
2. I would like to line break my long popup description to 100px...

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 120%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}
.main-header {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.header {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.name {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
.description {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.description:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.qt {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  text-align: right;
}
.price {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th class="main-header" colspan="4">Test Main Header</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="header">Name</td>
    <td class="header">Description</td>
    <td class="header">qt</td>
    <td class="header">Price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Test product name</td>
    <td class="description">Test long description lféjksdéflé lksajdf sadlkjlék sadflkjasd lfljkjlkjléas dflk</td>
    <td class="qt">22 pcs</td>
    <td class="price">$370</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**. I've edited it for you but please remember this for the future.

Comment: Thanks, and Sorry for it!

Comment: Just put your description text inside a `div` and apply the ellipsis stuff to that instead of the cell. https://jsfiddle.net/L604s0rz/2/

Comment: It's too large because you've made the cell `inline-block`

Comment: Thanks Chris for your solution!